# The static container already has a kernel associated with it

Tags: asp.net, azure, webforms, ninject

I have this error related to Ninject when deploy to Azure:

```
The static container already has a kernel associated with it!
```

But it works fine in local. And it has always been working on both local and Azure before, and I don't remember what changes happened recently (e.g., I didn't NuGet a newer version of Ninject). I checked related posts but still cannot solve my problem.

Here is the error page when after deployed to Azure:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The static container already has a kernel associated with it!

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: The static container already has a kernel associated with it!

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[NotSupportedException: The static container already has a kernel associated with it!]
   Ninject.Web.KernelContainer.set_Kernel(IKernel value) +68
   Ninject.Web.NinjectWebHttpApplicationPlugin.Start() +8
   Ninject.Web.Common.Bootstrapper.<Initialize>b__0(INinjectHttpApplicationPlugin c) +8
   Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.Map(IEnumerable`1 series, Action`1 action) +130
   Ninject.Web.Common.Bootstrapper.Initialize(Func`1 createKernelCallback) +140
   AlamomiAdmin.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon.Start() in c:\a\src\AlamomiUniverse\AlamomiAdmin\App_Start\NinjectWebCommon.cs:26

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +192
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +155
   WebActivatorEx.BaseActivationMethodAttribute.InvokeMethod() +57
   WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.RunActivationMethods(Boolean designerMode) +350
   WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.Run() +78

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Run on type WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager threw an exception with the following error message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation..]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +547
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +132
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +102
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +153
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +521

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Run on type WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager threw an exception with the following error message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation..]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9930568
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been frustrated by this for a week. Today I found the solution. I figured there must be two duplicate Ninject.dll/Ninject.Web.dll or whatever dll files from Ninject in Azure. So I must remove all existing files in Azure before I deploy. I deploy from Visual Studio.

So here is what I did. In Visual Studio, right click project, and select "Publish...". In the popup window, under "Settings", check the checkbox named "Remove additional files at destination". Deploy again.

Now it succeeds.